# que es lo que descargo en https://github.com/angular/angular-cli

Tags: nodejs, angular, angular5, angular-cli

quiero empezar a trabajar con angular js, he instalado Node.js y cuando corro el comando npm install -g @angular/cli la ejecución me da error se cual es la causa de este problema, embusqueda de una una solución encontre que puedo descargar angular cli desde el enlace que esta en la página oficial https://cli.angular.io/ con el vínculo GET STARTED, el cual me direcciona a https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/ descargo el todo. y cuado reviso todo es diferentes a los tutotiales. alguien tiene alguna referencia de como continual.

Comment: *Angular JS* es un poco antiguo, si vas a empezar empieza por la última versión de *Angular 2*, la 6 que no salió hace mucho. Yo seguiría el proceso "oficial" para preparar el entorno y empezar: https://angular.io/guide/quickstart. Si ya empiezan a aparecer errores, mejor desinstalar node o lo que tengas y comienza de nuevo.

Comment: Hola, bienvenid@ a StackOverflow en español, te sugiero hacer el [tour] para que tengas una mejor idea sobre el funcionamiento de la pagina y puedas dar a conocer tu pregunta de mejor manera. También puedes revisar [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para lo mismo.Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

@angular/cli no es el framework de Angular. Es una biblioteca para que puedas generar proyectos angular desde la línea de comando:

```
sudo npm i -g @angular/cli
```

Deja disponible el ejecutable `ng`. Luego puedes generar un proyecto ejecutando

```
ng new miproyecto
```

Eso creará una carpeta `miproyecto` dentro de la cual hay un scaffold de una aplicación Angular. Entras a esa carpeta, ejecutas `npm install` y ya tienes una aplicación funcional sobre la que puedes empezar a hacer tus adiciones y modificaciones.

Por otro lado, si clonas el repo de https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/ en realidad no tendrás el comando `ng` en tu línea de comando, sino que sólo podrás ejecutarlo dentro de tu copia local de ese repo haciendo primero `npm install` y luego `npm run ng`, que no es lo ideal. Mejor utiliza el camino con `sudo npm i -g @angular/cli`. Si no tienes privilegios sudo, puedes configurar npm para que los paquetes instalados globalmente se instalen en tu carpeta local.

Para esto además debes añadir la ruta de esos paquetes a tu $PATH (por ejemplo `/home/junior_molina/.npm-packages/bin`).

Comment: Que interesante, ahora quiero aprender Angular ;)

Comment: Recomiendo aprender [Vue](https://vuejs.org/). Me manejo bastante en Angular 2,3 y 4 y siento que Angular es un superset de Typescript, que es un superset de javascript. Es un lenguaje propio inspirado en javascript (esto también afecta parcialmente a React, porque su JSX es en buenas cuentas un mix de JS con HTML que lo hacen, en ese aspecto, un lenguaje distinto). Vue es derechamente javascript y no hay directivas mágicas que tengas que aceptar sin entender.

Answer (score 0):

AngularJs y Angular son frameworks diferentes. Tené en cuenta que lo que estás instalando al hacer `npm install -g @angular/cli` es el cliente(no el framework Angular) globalmente, y que te va a permitir correr los comandos. Lo que querés es instalar el cli localmente en tu directorio de proyecto de angular también(de esta manera vas a utilizar esa versión y si arrancas proyectos nuevos vas a tener un cli x cada proyecto para así evitar problemas de versiones).

Para iniciar un proyecto e instalar las dependencias (Angular, el cli, etc...) seguí [estos pasos](https://angular.io/guide/setup):

```
git clone https://github.com/angular/quickstart.git quickstart
cd quickstart
npm install @angular/cli --save  // notá el --save que agrega la dependencia al package.json si el comando falla, tenés algo mal configurado
npm install
npm start
```

Estos comandos van a descargar un template de proyecto de angular con lo básico para arrancar... revisá el archivo package.json para entender las versiones y paquetes que tiene el proyecto.

Comment: Pero si instalas @angular/cli en cada proyecto sólo lo usarás una vez para generar el proyecto local haciendo `$(npm bin)/ng miproyecto --directory ./` y de ahí en adelante será una dependencia sin uso. Si lo instalas globalmente, no habrá conflictos con los proyectos generados con anterioridad porque no usarás el cli en ellos.